# Observable Collections Collection Changed

Tags: .net, silverlight, observablecollection

Real quick on observable collections. I've been playing around with these in Silverlight doing some binding stuff, what have ya. Seems like the CollectionChanged event fires when removing from or adding to the collection. I'd like for something to fire when I change a property on one of the classes inside the collection. The collection property itself already has the RaisePropertyChanged. Do I need to do something special to the type class itself? So if I have this:

```
ObservabelCollection<Person> personcollection... and if I change a property like:

Person p = personcollection.where(e => e.FirstName == "Joey").FirstOrDefault();
if (p != null) { p.FirstName = "Joe"; }
```

I would expect something to happen in the UI but nothing changes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what you're trying to do but if im correct Observable Collection only raises the `INotifyCollectionChanged` event when items in it's collection changes. This will trigger changes in the UI.

It doesn't care if a property on one of it's objects in it's collection changes. You would need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface on the properties on these objects to trigger a change to the UI.

I had a read of [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd252944.aspx) which gave me some useful insight. Though it is aimed for WPF most of it still applies as Silverlight is essentially a subset of WPF.

As well as this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748365.aspx) article which states:

```
 In particular, if you are using OneWay or TwoWay (for example, 
 you want your UI to update when the source properties change dynamically), 
 you must implement a suitable property changed notification mechanism 
 such as the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. Ill be looking at this a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

To get updates for `Person` class you should implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) for them.

Comment: Yeah, I know this exists but I'm using the "RaisePropertyChange" which is inside this ViewModelBase class. I'll have to play around with this a bit more. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @DavidWhitten and the Person class derives from the ViewModelBase?

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged worked like a charm. Im set. Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

**INotifyCollectionChanged** supposed to notify somebody when the collection changed.

**INotifyPropertyChanged** supposed to notify somebody when a property of an object changed.

An object of a class must implement the interface and must fire the events correctly. So if you bind it via the Binding object, the UI can update itself.

**ObservableCollection** implements **INotifyCollectionChanged** correctly, but it has nothing to do with the objects it contains. Because if an object's property changed **that is not a CollectionChanged event**. That's a **PropertyChanged event** of the concrete object within the collection. So you have to implement the **INotifyPropertyChanged** interface in your Person class.

Answer (score 0):

The `ObservableCollection` does not report changes made to properties of the objects in the collection.

To get that behavior, you will have to hook the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event for each child object as they are inserted into your collection. You can do this in the collection's `CollectionChanged` event.  Don't forget to unhook the events when children are removed from the collection.